# What's the easiest way to start default mail client with message

Tags: java, email, html-email, email-client

I'm looking for the easiest way to open the system default mail client with a custom message.

Is there some way to make this OS independent?

Comment: What have you already researched?   For example, https://www.google.com/search?q=java+invoke+default+mail+client&oq=java+invoke+default+mail+client&aqs=chrome..69i57.10844j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: There are somethings on the internet but they all not os independent... but I'm looking for something that works on Mac, Win, and Linux

Comment: Read about [Desktop.mail(URI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail-java.net.URI-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class for this, it has a `mail(URI)` method.

> Launches the mail composing window of **the user default mail client**,
>   filling the message fields specified by a mailto: URI.

Here is an example :

```
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        String message = "mailto:someuser@somedomain.com?subject=mySubject&body=someBody";
        URI uri = URI.create(message);
        try {
            desktop.mail(uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The javadoc of `Desktop` states " allows a Java application to launch associated applications registered on the native desktop to handle a URI or a file", so as long as you have an application registered to handle this kind of URI (mailto URI) on your OS's desktop, it should work.

Comment: This ist nice ;)